# Как подружить ruby и apache2?

Tags: ruby, apache2

Вопрос, собственно, такой: хочу изучить ruby без рельсов. Но проблема в том, что мануалы все про RoR. Надо как-то запустить скрипты .rb через браузер, но что-то не выходит у меня.

Comment: Лучше учить руби через рельсы.

Answer (score 1):

Вам нужен не apache, a nginx. А вот и мануальчик http://habrahabr.ru/post/225313/

Answer (score 0):

Если вы новичок, могу посоветовать вам codecademy.com/tracks/ruby, ничего не нужно ставить, просто учите.

Чтобы запустить скрипт, сначала вам нужно поставить Ruby, если вы под linux, то лучше это делать через [RVM](https://rvm.io/rvm/install) (или на [хабре](http://habrahabr.ru/post/120504/)). В MocOS есть 2.1 или 1.9, так что ставить не нужно.

Если под Виндой, то советую поставить linux, но если вам очень-очень, ну, просто очень нужен вин, можно поставить [rubyinstaller](http://rubyinstaller.org/).

Потом зайти в папку и набрать:

```
ruby myscript.rb
```

Answer (score 0):

RVM лучше не ставить. Единственная киллер-фича gemsets с недавних времён спокойно заменяется bundler'ом. Так что ставь rbenv (*nix-only).

Answer (score 0):

Индейцев не треба, это не php, там много простых способов при обучении:

1. ruby file.rb в терминале
2. irb там же
3. Lifeserver в VScode
4. gem 'sinatra' для миниприложений
5. встрокнная библиотека TLCsocet написать свой сераер
6. для работы с БД отдельно полключается ActiveRecord, есть консоль, логер
7. на googl я видел плагины, но не пользовал